# StackOverflowError computing factorial of a BigInteger?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow, biginteger, factorial

I am trying to write a Java program to calculate factorial of a large number. It seems `BigInteger` is not able to hold such a large number.

The below is the (straightforward) code I wrote.

```
 public static BigInteger getFactorial(BigInteger num) {
      if (num.intValue() == 0) return BigInteger.valueOf(1);

      if (num.intValue() == 1) return BigInteger.valueOf(1);

      return num.multiply(getFactorial(num.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))));
  }
```

The maximum number the above program handles in 5022, after that the program throws a `StackOverflowError`. Are there any other ways to handle it?

Comment: That cant be the biggest for BigInteger data types.  Where is the stackoverflow exception being thrown?  Post more relevant code.

Comment: Yes, use the iterative algorithm. BigInteger is doing fine, getFactorial just ate all the stack space.

Comment: @harold (+1) - another example of why I think recursion is a harmful technique to teach college students, at least in languages without tail recurion.  It's an intellectual exercise, but ultimately not useful for anything interesting.

Comment: Recursion "not useful for anything interesting"? Meh.

Comment: @JonH: stack overflow is not the same thing as a numerical overflow, type of `num` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @CPerkins: there are compilers which perform tail call optimization (and it's guaranteed in most functional prg. languages) which avoids this problem. And some algorithms (tree traversal, for example) are inherently recursive. Whenever you use the .NET's Sort methods, you are using a recursive quicksort algorithm, so it's far from being *not useful for anything interesting*.

Comment: @Groo - And that is the reason why I said it cant be the biggest.  So my point was the exception wasn't because of the value of bigint but rather something else.

Comment: Not that this example is a simple tail-recursion anyway: it needs to be transformed with an accumulator. Maybe some compilers for some languages can do that automatically sometimes, but this one is tricky since the compiler would have to prove to its own satisfaction that `BigInteger.multiply` is associative.

Comment: @Groo - I agree that tree traversal, etc are more easily understandable as recursive, but any recursive algorithm can be transformed into an iterative one, and vice versa.  But it keeps coming back to tail recursion - without it, stack size imposes a limit on data set size. Perhaps I should redefine 'interesting'. :)

Comment: Note the behaviour of `BigInteger.intValue()` means that factorial of anything greater than or equal to 4,294,967,296 will be wrong http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue() (not that you have any hope of calculating such a value anyway)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem here looks like its a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) from too much [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) (5000 recursive calls looks like about the right number of calls to blow out a Java [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) and not a limitation of `BigInteger`.  Rewriting the factorial function iteratively should fix this.  For example:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Modified code to use static constants `BigInteger.ONE` and `ZERO`.

Comment: During algorithm class, I remembered a technique which used Push/Pop unto a Stack to avoid StackOverflow exception when implementing the extremely deep-recursive [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) in Java, especially for `A(4,1)` which took around 28 minutes to execute on Core2Duo T7250.

Comment: @ee.- What you're describing is replacing the runtime stack with an explicit stack.  This can be made to work, though the complexity of most algorithms written this way is often higher than the recursive version.

Comment: @templatetypedef I concur. The standard runtime stack in Java will immediately catches StackOverflow exception soon enough when running `Ackermann function` at `A(4,1)` using standard recursion approach. Explicit stack seems to resolve the problem, albeit the complexity of the explicit stack approach.

Answer (score 3):

The issue isn't BigInteger, it is your use of a recursive method call (`getFactorial()`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead, an iterative algorithm:

```
public static BigInteger getFactorial(int num) {
    BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    return fact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries from Google have a highly optimized implementation of factorial that outputs BigIntegers.  [Check it out](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#factorial%28int%29).  (It does more balanced multiplies and optimizes away simple shifts.)

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementations of factorial don't work out in real situations.

If you have a serious need, the best thing to do is to write a [gamma](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%20function) function (or `ln(gamma)` function) that will work not only for integers but is also correct for decimal numbers.  Memoize results so you don't have to keep repeating calculations using a `WeakHashMap` and you're in business.

Answer (score 0):

the way to call itself is not correct, since with extremely large numbers, it thunders due to StackOverflowError, the best thing for extremely large numbers is the factorial of 913, 999, or larger is to loop or while, doesnt call to same program.

```
for (   BigInteger i = new BigInteger ( "1" )   ;
        !salir ;)  {
 if ( i.equals ( n.add ( BigInteger.ONE ))  )
  salir = true ;
 else
  result = result.multiply ( i )   ;
 i = i.add ( BigInteger.ONE )   ;
}
```

12163485049042206946749724736917423124313249550721376830277183696171338521995973161718744951109676398599505257471162680799380935261770672523463219591124646229445686184968071875683982942570820112489175678513661829460758082038124263825166481377117262325001991144650478480569968642841960583108987251458163697432069329041904326101633320808727776810661412338796229880210758083841624400174632609317649060716767999189276870552125180983803419852432523869333711612352029137346197429403270651602216347392004694801287677671475365282776987118449954715691012108764632855111870536709027203753265093730818738435961569862401300380387004871324946014712363603408837620594183083200826512106498860217202580060173926721200943868734204625188016647392019895587604564553984348534890439288640333995675450432752502952355352296130379477769726508443629506757281394573033085262168863952975220492972812212802900238541794839215759977886734718396604180712625549023656564950153317119250646432632581266433450336751945032103038374494396938850670776140548721222569981739453425081538111070505375605999599798694412707969334355865462390267417390072870282911175422437209711413012757317629395597023109081217329401957532345473528103078477514627356096310762166690954403392635151101986608401691474039100378524129731737251773980269906395294832783306302266127044185772136268063808140742445191130732295414644715433452610681915586235272593117971093147111104189102538176953125223421726877375254012237195790808452247981464480285878781354984780175878496682014473065273384618148543511016905480849075070382227045493871105113920222222171845014760573754065588044064200508876128422530942200976153237845374634950925170803332062323664415954273765806666179561910158025851420039257374225819847320929841979768611843834620743932079508340665874617276766805340532918924070464842985314534360948869034460365716638763104542017603189470478558441910354421869355176285538436228561510332603894875490835086993288456106975341836657803904082120553283859339974091440815233887629443123469486888969984860769442669719077410063613781676911369843309363721135439235892949980815971801740507432256873847329906996784543245754384519082471217651504130032421983345669479141552352889742681591710749079875054324716601643127763716943540472450078238142626725119301672472582048950878458205735676063853933791289083768382829140858938623821815063750035616541805142685143903466007920598739949064898593268731016155668823857672032973249449938169202229040549420649997355676795639871733882538570284834737651640581370087547371621351872784493665812159704137361095026100314516513867366731750395713413885618403765160388999118756130158772722405831284747011446979088037859908219639234926856898339103836259345651182734995109635978258303609054054133949611354686494198694622630820842409378634619506735505101681323027120725599769730403295060858956299033826616916776012495887532429101111275905908775157705362353574071841809921532144160521787901732381503919353107559697968510401097820425026153672958767735635279524102334989019378686994232948427766993318440049078270721817908216836301777547144077732717636446325911200494687214722366176586187463372532460706376249207254265632218770655712392694995553238437811821085275895064877000009331619453402506523751069309636781259783412881164393187570392150525542337810970451636896051276475842684804997916411739675212895856554693938726733735565521699829259311809237265411060847226396154348661661604783089919611801097038976296474943590711080178851902207130372417322809906833398468862225404145092372602600762329113096442976964183513621938030252112940551992349551342267958237346752741784010733968593185894895561995509890619602863850524730888480387888800673971421396930537121946866782839252247235220475301310778867640225811890537838471210849719794576160075083353774308926598845984282732241482605227486992709642383473840014062158346877015806426886619666532059053677112500665318935399403503079489568206873985825616366785577741118741453296836723977149120439942792171325757393723699865726596128186731263936329538811020710204785614485388875854840561326551730234051458809750059646279920911348105033319548906810523831893377477921289039054500008678526957523518399948677617364254754183343107487590403778594738925826092822767831127727428929454521257139753840736092951182917641349503278830294580819179694748862060235872746130018579090701840093245048686908174983822933389691464912014630687084025661138176937594020298842544034367277709751688455684822959748292983966428624098538959919176957501854496207574039819023494994335383254085426173860269513604573012877665145482931528611999131579919323898356103208951725207155903099998631825027642742717992436924104134045650743725968698204004259933350570001466009969516639519241313068956023015461917622746664423441010809814659714060942134911039555577856492617541637336924345159196728185292429992663850538453756906457122160691338515943039730367680310215338908066562837909603148480049985566305955819743906163182333553719743547024192853578881519846805190720893135306012678885156307313466530333962849605521868455008776490930061970160423903489980973753807943851090830337605892630963751104139980179694905406208951612390527249175626684685434471006508249051367941493220665425979276832077444015417764028950063004600209600498998960912548942808887298960054705850046611986884741121574752679085290869294275289430836672696209741722964935699477201535898966276744978610326184169834691334525826005926742831357963621586680484267825952998187203778201843249639326677346266163447899897927936371824498122110277210440924133919953807981684998748519704840657411800157284336617852016551581160349759062838097301655639930088006407527243018911705306356703237848492700563399390378993638665299698961266277327246960377685901211921020953488093116769844657419637987198031897730661035518005428762562296761333592523622916850768444572128909154224862934581785234792156242599760170976510630781860548651847137279683231436662143171425065260669468739062538933834027949399578297059323284108151155288783381471658680023719047776323889967328753842413094915586554497841251603962633951224816286415578182368374962300995444761516797809947880981975494582170926890991614626043345208883060072001202670734734211444135895168575667940511683108556828868349925083108192122182929323872501828909787337833654141964813913199944337669997496689449034099102813731407084863869426412384391484920165518216332264054836468053486743947770285699157870639232517217866631670704013168462139768590347356310961553666286603285728644225586057552841464915998899038795439047436444086889768865209168982417616470493663033470140321314743773893998257347083091600755051323177104011150035127434382501749105860662819276460839161929336527218427705216494031558735254276625959920464110200441485337135574878672914568308474489787331619196232512688908699612850179199366925778186144665483415104028537797647194119555946456819127396464245982489162031688969979240685470895815176620729919780149544698978798539631561677846809796692632778732864183536822048349068286661342798084438547692491864579865220364686264685862069010494011080606335103902753309390937872989397285969868062051460445450597479597072230869801849111194748173632317596604811123584970359556582467189700918057188063049145776029324135233447613955040566887659042189457443662476960273384738218862932961132081225246292249181012274709916453581006947805827685475286811696980247520539353636514073363446581520176150276578571651853790660559994147527522148446966443118416977531417775098130244714255222778220312929784463129906397936069852332656194242345032378208016840839002882848287006870692137789643229720824799813183414995516286762760985236954356245470419143442439376676575899369326090347485791050424185181402390090135651013992798423303182252071217827232170435029400364859164871881512952141851074922145589728287579425103303585292388740841719000680209893883840389910802025283741323194500688241662466929813036989528675758236219635764858067101104587204351038640820344119303741919140066072028751028484428190826193474688984719702369051320445501408799721691569217897758332595105043532321416885925241446041303560623077258689518674972129945842499219417948297785532430496094954276742487723388065851433414178805024078823425466172743825539584335034634351721314039011369098717269813174707951993372607118699835219006526161886441295698180167991722959186042916411608094390390509984131517310044431399458626896441805295837900799159667315586700907616204456751850815869840665791628671136290862555502714528184298570201693625324277412413760699361803308301487197177305309676248248023765810840715777347570851892495114972485665882281030749879190100278030711616637972109376308324810742317177940818355906589021862526841739646041077313329501849682738613545217667171681797771500919758158157988516516795453825086230995657073071158238365356770880788800577639529783825320407575970076847169396857027162252623858369237561679208625836977630454948356987177757709829846461610162646798759236966581194306448849510878221697240929323777885070565752964537062223085756314235448498242529614164538581969959726518244608745719803747696597612567299452259735760244826680947985883739389570616817182377889401256082168002005389092719367744857203320658017493884576186424554838665314513795274800734035608719534270126060337164701375856048654363901062141826890520582317465610672078956776525628686181445309653339256338396662416000955712007686932949589249825910846415676570992923882803487328258753471155186666206722054572979246442893600343921870796201520523250072204654451487582618961890473068844804303483999366396642610655190893049013485404560360360469240011011713347536476046458763394022107832315925136667331730617881146398709821778446933655516735682939603854785794442372626077220889476925353973617275546840543289180756906050458612444678645647130878947110920140986244975093170293659379622711149695000581604335472900656017553161615699495185070207123889609578885788194288970955562880487396303546156048141003602644267837820772497955089316577697050307744242790217987949328611675006567257757391784647180592414233396219447526439166175911094676431965116177807628683685735366824541594082461383385953477105414301342500742227464965957421471279683678124278184350923741516290477038191814884178486608961520078029229885521933957893168584631851906340246021899921196859231990620400432314343125794539559608742760867056768808296547429360023137195614236317051738638034301970393073367515424275757152285459458785317651887147722777206132341065834491796670608670808398615816038136152094673544478001842472211884202415250864698190759660714039893645424361172333253279626993550957866918466991440793300402444438290143979525960293059615754502253860204762852418030412728436454109645473453040635939345243190063179187763396809409728906720453352270938620981421338562345877950401607794119930833626003763651521986828754741288809053565655561027935633710854030441595395016984152605033095276333322295016290569649885622137420372301757593982599561415284941052664371518494782518475630618284267431812049023389177412517356856121204992157051946535833451332852409168009553896044697360518141763376434636675120162229488010979311308529730337926754890627024664043905160319578625660392391898556193590257726456099435811981285205080500878862470185530315997956401394610695776659572041078784551436284035320626958693980888374452010064952678751869872133337331352034435776840577021320780528054681074736052818658217778550597007633261398926727972566156772125390366471538537798639652164773836417356037929579725384265221099096054297528255212307983676214640717129341774739866764087769390974577027934049893430595565376440871869807758676822670688640431530344638708469614758204128413698678877647007782181428595177319665714154683690111102556270940843292970997556040279856532732679453977038113683997142014620489043681895233853823144075044153113410125196759505154422050262075390157584574656131849644725367211298941533903783232267449386695045124062567298152819395952141832997528394859470535176013876812825511598944640073349829168585586285506001143206071765372098560472283822780107385188020333362922530751836721014716293007336328287886728579328067618325229202022126761063125753028541470126800965319207145879830725869604355355857002571761114332967627595300927380541699243014085490492307543268955868673932578055232204197242219535183574867625815084952641509665052394906405255955607788956533186423967953027196227696471074041257389011495754043222142586324398349346017002557053731629655322364920857640612969758680124818879915120334125317862467262728343084161108972719281631222826251556351372351094800251166232321210274540337495271477904264019643355215254358600749660168513258599263791194225782670280040387779015574145227179218094940888598933287043335498242275778414109752514069040487754025151306980642336935115250706586899319447709318468623760370535199953498960889382897382762377881193757874304578660964273786073984190094788913759856577395841835377022766909288986574495586451282386636577985704560274560972755407030298387863340986990783968423390740969474805440586200139689828880699127257611596274467873359381030090058527611482603719156507285526747346045165728558709276356678084352176816660339629091347398103311356953598212566796086879046730687205988592721139331922178183249655585427450571734150150726929476559643332340733225409598764933545129670623465427621980832165815689588711601966737899546259071786572775380294186574918688314498898824375701038835516629312163742304074203493304616437562863967070315013646494594046118385376414920967821439665341750860313192959493771639297645288314857651994175537606832411446234865635330539602378426045477048549881790165077724188526330678455596471098518955869018342115362511749764901363638256625414099467752094116326740158523458252001799768087097991519502352629886958752475701151136296021900224755298360700007022608897072897489478653009049527799274267042689875114683965188834782938325681076724311189868147609221839943478463790752967755184571871614503036349551043350610027479595663148798236767888846388079865942406222018395833608338569489272569023658875154748115630089742036965038034824795225100438008326222044502716550825886342829429790433609459194550973394372105868874896074207589017931819115109491755154595743392186059289575496288962133426417579412908064210007154123612193194140390535453340883616885419516471761645066134048519994381210055097667794674378346221569845570535128057663913643177796743126812170662687431678319346230943955605967667762876397673499323905994928868876352157232338188728266732000341823798529578286238125481471878675306213463049889915471398523906331460149742384800165808425960962214698300427935151956449261066132529527103002892100803606421159004524041140464728305361660099487976323919177801098094555755297581537004359795973441956913377866237485096825507565109292166262577009556889832441844070403527515813676900891466653638102199899928650874415046044701191043914687096734943849720832864104310414475813464675809306977581776171028446907747183666455900326297311426508016159246767787938430158594869345652392877481044934867758670971406341010783803730994430833381651912147968946686783841973580192317918706524293826271750280207606395167493662932636889454140235451538498585724702065167685821195060965981131629218619008858617117311083064200819568118956350361451019841112618422869738951079281243170520079594734237542574307320739046438143098595598956449659643170642980142089290017698099052023785450245423417925958614497445432015182282430429434104008833373783884339992403550924297000973835650257098048364460921009480932751483676476167416010572717289745587707556298039839457318073963335764790963418296851534574780599462035330741551273524552276067842104840705148824317885585925104715246158792332418666707735627077821841679136789129679434926390510381802045511357155584205184162594438029366506370388059373524373317076813661812535958101447448653463747236170206334216919691177654574518747146165147494596350255927684090688049107546108446776956919483607685388037780287136210934916031699402173724682239130538922333009959121435750920288565264205636314701216952145476835576303646065745885748208475881594077798897381195757236380540846758142496139750369341969491380675381268787603508089477441110294410178440797348004234037528727999318002537909418844910679317313900823024991726967915420068734923544609732413867294707258269127708665363872072341004691475087673932012775397889701947937394492364530097865731226306656944167332705137247099591650599412147691799464798417440702983945312565137433317995567064360452213119605774114761576862547083883994293935869758291313336543569406892188795562376859288844113234094000118050565578181353192076130167472271620968072160538063957055778285652436426493845814716801422198302675822593315317711930213845921616287714628228167503486107623505004568106120246159852554349073656381447515132838887833551373508559397951920873480166827066468160167791279713564106745905410312611308075200617339385117969005181035891913321761379461501891051682927162594340875733802497485695129311445969048253431548897216364386957682428110372844713045531518057033561927231132929431051940787206444360125351717682102772365627363833712073563892031052791523008508105860383388677038703554466042606978932625487023417974857236486966895153180834739782998393827111895420484344177352974337439987931714508746162489553834144977653057947309184883967549433858881784108039886946593086578275729155297354070766025392713924148611403035056824386977957589303914194319220803571673891361412285150058009033071702643249805127741661087494859467848267330889299008531206965835381131654632938163336298493021452473212660893743207015067270273393701857749195544845027493231275537955240438722429342093259247135392953524002157336077604257144319965351177563949991761887133338197691954305276652797892481097727487679652308539244294521299748288901418663189280618455573746039093007595394971013697715080870508292136902621929261370978186830031969110879322132956908616293836927786805335167608490358813817385052124400818350241110964262825169970298767031224599645501009050467750175852745966271828547689773569792172331814893717322190706398396940451521202678264999023362838691390579862127377892759350223156414686651885102563998943845063399119742700287233667310663788962341026115961933305696116742042629711486473636884770820159682075563226578929153221534191938555545489624197819047383267400280695015978998009699944270873231851966929057562105432041512060599796605487849991485671240653953259227374445977277311095003109544550422226846429358004357131974963840121833998020040540317188326992305147050598113267612775535056612810203690086267146205022588417037532136114748012249749951068206043701633730929158994002609667521613577502202864606502562022778340006795075004190398430210897009693306499578939233692385875084752934797699014853404323987358720885520244535890954785312122170322778362997534857054079787207733421075472293475977899797087556321138590318237778328889139476497838330189763971985684758483724519787353744630051193408174858097744266385562412846688755577504185609974460628149150579810720147473955150618693931667164712412677942555977247749209499452111628018663436899052373268980269748284186692547860268725507224021839761233723832899206565669448295773423225935212522905456377694655459345176860636221132245160333575062243977699184708544262631610480380809418903164393076139498023804602430458791486429137820568007487393684492887733340586211919056857363237768973854474412408073811682464508955403704310295060710017028245026193241725899336201207302355165238953352922602002749914244586915933417904873271620887208189395668180826194396413496319007939718740730752896777260180893243235102045964008311259902819065022135331329916642567249012114619278299651672407516867720717815212126542941678340503777828471981294279074204577829277139002370030727876538594875313966328959137546840570026906272224818399417419039758299704389800493085028125210993149271369100205219007703644146920373004494738886544276767254453577674703443127817499612828207452793233365478195612111974228078279757675035824432994256758817168587664196797195337157011982048355232798418434911396237688621840382580932277036799699963758838180005697136492355920377590422541734690273237680807184884543981154685095551863958195487211971732080413729155103982692415074510722292695206242955096143205143965279317760449199730127174453276263438448795175352247342466738098054987567062162389825393421959919026282862287220356567197170695236396118019964924047099539014859045894311469237343866094068041274240640386752867321755847422228245711126381981828690566941884777939430603369221230179183033986093598735629392700693746706730005097345822380429462654612878978014672906275233752181331373686845629411392816682182859418096515404497507375275581139340607919173776254700354650145314213527300791709088987023300744273841622528991317771137144893300431551866995722353562162624035552593697754445190362782090978517009149791572477658249983703653490628571140661416378872244847925060783861938013620778688217243015313641994952270117522855763767501798556477491738020768018842193888463964876930795711844676164782635937732264390577040132574886090758207876309882588722724884948611794233632279599977930696486723736897394492329444247257456507355696772947062750264062477336018432035601532092390337201122372076596563349181216607384280875490769305392829527800723572809855542033780564881600655098928890158029842940181080094285550728175443094019962155030689652130781801894745119011556855663053072447967215742442335054833479236161461566358318447464038534386682511216422984979120367528175891300088718982496631414722881008326928509895623600049566395273838316834742400554844316002260300749526898197931926258217662402926515420443391351272142110634685590038866582739118993973837101136293385247549458822173369677195920464354029768337413716567993897465324167471047931267528745259115825639989075647388552141882615918279169225791653402652388318281340458965112369370800920664272293823419417055756132407718869865795499981924979210206527167823305291405180719044294334022314525104809521237905816065782847807873169585926493270749748080895910289441544955349021440191172487543300700182744308914084996636520410811104299081236664410009933328531913164823590475391196172774351911079226530290799510638639961967544761206593607349386216317828761053545367892695159224899886450121853729039571815365890174826786749228554590583863617047939358865684863427221350877742689572996101891499942862690952412129823782533633951664955471332186073539910031837858548556878552841435375009304761082212167127190725902040986172502136284111389897452524419330962829863679927221412530234153897992261407397110762826016192189598254415314095104610066038168340253724066629312452745904169776752200487125409152581966610050058200810877451943910079220941803328770130040185544082946729056888389281961561207572207180518415819033344472842624960738722165223137914639335122850614878518858009309932072075173296722818481409258553901614304733881045077653599887292910656694573875865502284668696536059723434010793545540041572195094630372543232579392822744584052480061412443471073500656869031452403489458532819374839234215197631571835889553978300671205357382604493148857461803687670147740694201834931260043084067728598045181829840509419286140022078532950072515851734006694402682429940109741076849348325082735662809196699112360981917347293265481019418387087006639623670690042748034958506838836303465627425484968363873171284152645089612902595428121469350728960736498186966240287193856290010334306895633859432552654022631270680717797277958778571004735288631831542091507578278467902765106820945006026126891212234016835316491133413120015103460428682935497183335707389948963595469772121891890492346660536476442753037499102215370950936007014092727685624339238388202026162457036642564126651017384051258803294039886432909818913633611633856550487448136702081795391851681190007256447185226245736688585093442262822745864455564784755171183011950122963209008475966679348119213121402901808281121634056614961300910493612756055655579115631526753332013395285976082105039841692703663475756900680908358786003422422213570397768718680606615900357791162568456716603054772219022650982041802265878179923968828488457171775024752654541622434068050500838926619971060625993861188938219869679827306255358118135680341694154486054665634018585109040002116090126893478754164124830281470984644378790839286942790211559683541999929165626370153777007470957903930629862533134608720974556657646333186252347296976566622781616735001483296694249425609782359549023238557692574630776374152693482903816930319303439531516760787955471666671515706180935162246996632054298427968810109307437530195774632434410108586473236201546197032862052383612153876161233735607438907967442135821563089594504366638942659933518198997337069323757088389499609603749012011435690924530893049509133293720902475793977562535428584461890457151663846860184248942626378057586876967229445997085141550213446192079606677155519318218903005495901938901679865369869397991276656340122101385603885591523735698037732693094010759746327506223964996570343863472386956538279457502121611424758348525262022722253540458636959984193680483955042143140825955008032593319083114894945508139194815005781808616338553454541116457335790005424367288491839264974474706721771818919101827704859652584825024430952093013376345922922946474418773444973461917886898671075314504233676200280847485751224053966257031121614387353474683948600568717913873016591782048153967410109225955836053242763154270155138461203300437309283616362069837080014529992314326750044464904901537965016846315423553089592123021287364700784918273562321814964612129558235401718655162427388910314927423456152468326569072856206070162535159877195379806799961340549196569604763391214082719294909055117393431902361500559420227235633728088717149162482996847599368630278780496585959494283568399373477920987280911592443466503939395252096824772997869131006279562601197271002735034881170358314349520250062700222682419434661372355880690864167047086474256461288170675349819448518816317137465612387185099064699019903529978848621216966430677654496909523483199420649793053149406436109820973355723645687404215370620482383864986429877973348147401563259694122502522304081884292895309273123864903113205198598130374419211930419246448501392194993510864468998580959250694316558897717277884546765492723157444627315505297201064322839105891922689247926966403302045718513115413058747315661278912855702254104379649213788674200180130570570903259335935937345257125664261533234839237321575509994496017202047113966354095216678324366958506716059451818871028724787320530960976598943660876604751003466687521946725001045339812758172272273899826559227329923136427476222071547007416758805077061684092217491499468991980112069324569361631183886115412425595388436905423803601251526696856622766069404895968443596765910663898253715315800544922864900430085746464306553794659063128038762026829687043263142541655246241022657214340415850666224846885249041456508333733925581199065971462294767263594404730933210514800751972217580742490135875955535843264568889395626499955244585453649104400258540931023527963398066396723394739577263855102707097818201911411707466895316919773294026799430539833324019346977883862563801874558029813446853488635171294756478488499001953558841307674872629971694428977852.....................................

with number of digits:5051358

maximum number to calculate:913999