# How can i extend data type in java

Tags: java

How i can create my own data type in java that could store a 16-byte integer value

the longest data-type in java by size is "long" which is 8-byte and it could store 19-digit integer value but, i want to find the factorial of 25 and the factorial of 25 is 26-digit(15511210043330985984000000). now the problem is i have no such a data-type in java that could store such huge value of 26-digits or more.

if there is any

```
public long factorial(int number)
{
    int i=1;
    long factorial=1;

    for(i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
        factorial = factorial * i; 
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: seems to be you need to make a class which can store 16  byte or more data value and you need to implement explicit arithmetic or logical operation in your own way or what you actually required. This can possible n byte if u can implement using string. And It will be generic through out.

Answer (score 5):

> Now the problem is i have no such a data-type in java that could store such huge value of 26-digits or more.

Have you looked at [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)? Note that this is a class (a reference type) rather than a value type, but it's immutable which means you can think of it as being somewhat value-like.

Answer (score 4):

> now the problem is i have no such a data-type in java that could store such huge value

That's not quite true. There is [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992471/367273) for an implementation of factorial that uses `BigInteger`.