# Hive factorial UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to find the factorial of a number in Hive. There's currently no Hive function to do that, so I've tried to write my own. This is my code:

```
package com.guy.hive.udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils;


public final class Factorial extends UDF {

public LongWritable evaluate(final LongWritable s){
        int n = (int) s.get();
        int fact = (int) ArithmeticUtils.factorial(n);
        return new LongWritable(fact);
    }
}
```

When I run this Hive query:

```
select factorial(c) from (select count(*) as c from test_table) ;
```

I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial.evaluate(long)  on object com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial@37483748 of class com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial with arguments {39514210:java.lang.Long} of size 1
```

Can anyone help with this?

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable)  on object com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial@5faa5faa of class com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial with arguments {39514210:org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable} of size 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1030)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:842)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.flush(GroupByOperator.java:1077)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1006)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathArithmeticException: arithmetic exception
        at org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils.factorial(ArithmeticUtils.java:317)
        at com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial.evaluate(Factorial.java:50)
        ... 24 more
```

[EDIT 1 - added imports to Java code.]

[EDIT 2 - added StackTrace

Comment: Try using LongWritable instead of long as the parameter.

Comment: I'll try, but the parameter passed by Hive is a long: 39514210:java.lang.Long

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this as well, actually. It's gotten my curiosity. The error message does not seem to give much info. Is there no other message, stack trace, or Caused By clause?

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable)  on object com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial@1c6f1c6f of class com.vm.hive.udf.Factorial with arguments {39514210:org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable} of size 1

Comment: That's what I got with the LongWritable. There is a stack trace, I'll post it in the question.

Comment: @GuyNeedham Your full stack trace provides the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem. The problem is not in Hive but in the ArithmeticUtils `factorial` method. See that it throws a `MathArithmeticException`? According to the docs, this will come when "the result is too large to be represented by a long."

This must be what's happening in your case. Try passing in a smaller number to the method.

Also, note that the `factorial` method is deprecated. The docs recommend using the CombinatoricsUtils.factorialLog(int) method instead.

Comment: Yeah I saw that when I was posting the stack trace. I do have a need to find factorials of large numbers though, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @GuyNeedham You may need to write your own custom factorial implementation using the java `BigInteger` class. Then the method could either return a BigInteger or a String representing the corresponding number (which could be arbitrarily big)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that as well as using logs. I tried Stirling's approximation but my value was still too large.

Comment: Interestingly, this is getting quite involved. I'm trying to avoid writing my own factorial method, and for other reasons can't upgrade Apache commons math, so I'm stuck with their method which errors out where n > 19. The Stirling approximation doesn't become reliable until n > 100, so there's a big old gap there. I think I'll just use Python!

Comment: @GuyNeedham You could use a pre-written BigInteger factorial method implemented iteratively. It should be good enough for your purposes, and will be much faster than in Python in general. See the accepted answer to this question for the implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992437/stackoverflowerror-computing-factorial-of-a-biginteger

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I'll definitely try it. I would question the assumption that Python will always be slower though. In my work with Hadoop I often find that streaming through a Python script can outcompete a Java MapReduce or a Hive UDF. In this case, it would probably be the case as using a function call rather than a whole extra MapReduce step to find the factorial will definitely be better. Context - modelling large counts with the Poisson distribution and trying not to transform the distribution as accuracy is important.

Comment: @GuyNeedham Fair point. I don't have any experience with Hadoop so I'll defer to your experience here. Hopefully you do find a solution that works for you and meets your performance expectations. Good luck!